# Automatically open downloaded file based on URI

Tags: android, download, uri

I'm building a website that is browsable on android devices, where the user can navigate to a page and click on a link to download the .APK file. Currently this system is functional, but I'm trying to figure out a way of streamlining the process.

Currently, the user downloads the file and Android notifies the user that a file has been downloaded. The user then has to go to their downloads section and open the file themselves.

Is there any way of telling Android to automatically open the file when download completes, or perhaps a URI action that will tell Android to prompt the user to open it when it is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Most web browsers (if not all) make their own downloading requests using the [DownloadManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). As far as I know you have no way of influencing their way of starting an intent.

Only thing that comes to my mind - and is probably not a viable solution in your case - is to have another app that listens with BroadcastReceiver for the event of finished download.